# Importar Backup e Diferencial Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

Estou tendo um problema com a importação de um backup para o servidor secundário:

A topologia:
Servidor Produção >> Servidor contingencia.

Quando é realizado a importação do Backup Full ele importa sem nenhum problema. 
O problema ocorre quando realizo a importação do Backup diferencial, o qual acusa um erro (msg 3117), 
Porem quando realizo a importação do do backup full juntamente o backup diferencial (indiferente de qualquer um deles) a importação ocorre sem problema algum, porem essa utilização não é produtiva devido ao tempo de importação e consumo de processamento da maquina.

Scripts:

```
/*TRANLACT-SQL*/
/*FULL*/
RESTORE DATABASE ASCCLUB  
   FROM DISK = 'D:\SQL\2017\Janeiro\23\FULL\20170123_HORA010000_FULL.bak'
   WITH REPLACE, NORECOVERY;  
/*DIFF*/
RESTORE DATABASE ASCCLUB
   FROM DISK = 'D:\SQL\2017\Janeiro\23\DIF\20170123_HORA170000_DIF.bak'
   WITH RECOVERY;
```

Erro quando importo somente o Dif:

```
Msg 3117, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The log or differential backup cannot be restored because no files are ready to rollforward.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: Você não pode fazer um backup diferencial sem o backup full. O nome já diz, ele é a diferença entre algum ponto. O que você tem que fazer é um backup de log

Comment: Entendo, faço a importação do backup Full sem problemas, e logo em seguida faço a importação do Dif, em um mesmo sql ele vai sem problemas, porem quando realizo um script e o dif em sequencia ocorre esse erro.

Comment: Sim, o que você precisa, pelo que entendi no seu problema é fazer o backup de Log. Esse pode ser restaurado sem precisar de base, mas irá englobar apenas o período que foi determinado. Eu vou escrever uma resposta detalhando melhor pra você

Comment: Agora entendi, vou espera sua explicação mais completa e vou testar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para responder a sua pergunta, vou utilizar a definição de 3 tipos de backup disponíveis no SQL Server, o backup completo, diferencial e de log de transação.

O backup completo, como o nome já diz, faz uma cópia de todos os dados disponíveis no momento da execução.

O backup diferencial copia os dados que foram alterados a partir do último completo, vem disso o nome, já que é uma diferença dos dados desde o último completo.

O backup de log copia os dados alterados em um determinado período. Esse método serve para que você possa restaurar um banco a partir de determinado ponto ou determinada hora.

Então para o seu caso o backup de log é mais indicado.

Você pode utilizar o seguinte comando para realizar o backup de log:

```
BACKUP LOG ASCCLUB
TO DISK = 'D:\SQL\2017\Janeiro\23\LOG\20170123_HORA170000.TRN'
GO
```

E para restaurar:

```
RESTORE LOG ASCCLUB FROM 'D:\SQL\2017\Janeiro\23\LOG\20170123_HORA170000.TRN' WITH RECOVERY;  
GO
```

**Referências:**

[Tipos de backup no SQL Server](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/13799.tipos-de-backup-no-sql-server.aspx)

[Backups de log de transações (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms191429.aspx)

Comment: Fiz o teste, porem não funcionou corretamente, seguindo o mesmo problema de só importar ele caso importe seguidamente do backup Full, se importar o full e depois de um minuto ele acusa o mesmo erro mencionado a cima.

Comment: O Full tem que ser feito apenas com uma vez com esse tipo de backup.  Depois vc pode fazer quantos de log vc quiser

Comment: Não entendi bem, o que falou, no caso eu vou necessariamente precisa importa todos os logs gerados ?

Comment: Não.  Vc só precisa importar a partir do último que foi importado